# TensorFlow GradienTape crashes with InvalidArgumentError when working on sparse Tensors

Tags: tensorflow, sparse-matrix, automatic-differentiation

I am encountering strange behavior when trying to evaluate the derivatives of a result obtained by sparse tensor operations. If I blow up all sparse inputs to dense before operating on them, the following code works as expected (first part of the following code), but it crashes with `InvalidArgumentError` when I do the same with sparse tensors. In addition, I get `while_loop` Warnings as below. As in the actual problem of course more operations and much bigger and more tensors are involved, I essentially have to collect the entries of `c` in sparse mode. Can anyone make (more) sense of this behavior?

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
a=tf.SparseTensor(indices=[[0,0],[1,1]],values=np.array([1,1],dtype=np.float32),dense_shape=(2,2))
b=tf.SparseTensor(indices=[[0,1],[1,0]],values=np.array([-1,-1],dtype=np.float32),dense_shape=(2,2))
#dense mode...
f1=tf.Variable([1,1],dtype=np.float32)
with tf.GradientTape() as gtape:
    c=tf.sparse.to_dense(a)*f1[0]+tf.sparse.to_dense(b)*f1[1]
print(gtape.jacobian(c,f1)) #... works fine
#sparse mode...
f2=tf.Variable([1,1],dtype=np.float32)
with tf.GradientTape() as gtape:
    c=tf.sparse.add(a*f2[0],b*f2[1],0)
    c=tf.sparse.to_dense(c)
print(gtape.jacobian(c,f2)) #... InvalidArgumentError

#WARNING:tensorflow:Using a while_loop for converting SparseAddGrad
#WARNING:tensorflow:Using a while_loop for converting SparseTensorDenseAdd
#WARNING:tensorflow:Using a while_loop for converting SparseTensorDenseAdd
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
#InvalidArgumentError                      Traceback (most recent call last)
#<ipython-input-10-d449761ef6b2> in <module>
#     12     c=tf.sparse.add(a*f2[0],b*f2[1],0)
#     13     c=tf.sparse.to_dense(c)
#---> 14 print(gtape.jacobian(c,f2)) #InvalidArgumentError
#c:\program files\python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\backprop.py in jacobian(self, target, sources, unconnected_gradients, parallel_iterations, experimental_use_pfor)
#   1187       try:
#   1188         output = pfor_ops.pfor(loop_fn, target_size,
#-> 1189                                parallel_iterations=parallel_iterations)
#   1190       except ValueError as err:
#   1191         six.reraise(
#c:\program files\python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\parallel_for\control_flow_ops.py in pfor(loop_fn, iters, fallback_to_while_loop, parallel_iterations)
#    203       def_function.run_functions_eagerly(False)
#    204     f = def_function.function(f)
#--> 205   outputs = f()
#    206   if functions_run_eagerly is not None:
#    207     def_function.run_functions_eagerly(functions_run_eagerly)
#c:\program files\python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\def_function.py in __call__(self, *args, **kwds)
#    826     tracing_count = self.experimental_get_tracing_count()
#    827     with trace.Trace(self._name) as tm:
#--> 828       result = self._call(*args, **kwds)
#    829       compiler = "xla" if self._experimental_compile else "nonXla"
#    830       new_tracing_count = self.experimental_get_tracing_count()
#c:\program files\python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\def_function.py in _call(self, *args, **kwds)
#    893       # If we did not create any variables the trace we have is good enough.
#    894       return self._concrete_stateful_fn._call_flat(
#--> 895           filtered_flat_args, self._concrete_stateful_fn.captured_inputs)  # pylint: disable=protected-access
#    896 
#    897     def fn_with_cond(inner_args, inner_kwds, inner_filtered_flat_args):
#c:\program files\python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\function.py in _call_flat(self, args, captured_inputs, cancellation_manager)
#   1917       # No tape is watching; skip to running the function.
#   1918       return self._build_call_outputs(self._inference_function.call(
#-> 1919           ctx, args, cancellation_manager=cancellation_manager))
#   1920     forward_backward = self._select_forward_and_backward_functions(
#   1921         args,
#c:\program files\python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\function.py in call(self, ctx, args, cancellation_manager)
#    558               inputs=args,
#    559               attrs=attrs,
#--> 560               ctx=ctx)
#    561         else:
#    562           outputs = execute.execute_with_cancellation(
#c:\program files\python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\execute.py in quick_execute(op_name, num_outputs, inputs, attrs, ctx, name)
#     58     ctx.ensure_initialized()
#     59     tensors = pywrap_tfe.TFE_Py_Execute(ctx._handle, device_name, op_name,
#---> 60                                         inputs, attrs, num_outputs)
#     61   except core._NotOkStatusException as e:
#     62     if name is not None:
#InvalidArgumentError:  Only tensors with ranks between 1 and 5 are currently supported.  Tensor rank: 0
#    [[{{node gradient_tape/SparseTensorDenseAdd_1/pfor/while/body/_56/gradient_tape/SparseTensorDenseAdd_1/pfor/while/SparseTensorDenseAdd}}]] [Op:__inference_f_6235]
#Function call stack:
#f
```

Comment: Franz, I don't think jacobian accepts a SparseTensor as input. Not all classes in tf accept RaggedTensors or SparseTensors

Comment: That is correct. But the argument to jacobian is actually dense (coud be sparse in my case but I can live with just one dense representation), and is accepted, but then gives a much deeper error. So I suspect something is broken there if I made no mistake I do not see.